# why is my cat staring at me?

Tags: cats, behavior, psychology

Sometimes I find myself in this situation where I don't know what to do. My cat is staring at me, and I feel guilty not knowing what she wants from me. She keeps staring until she feels tired and sometimes sleeps while sitting, not laying. As if there was something really interesting and needs thinking that made her forget to lay down to sleep. I blink or close my eyes to show her a cat kiss, but she still looks at me either after she blinks using two eyes or without blinking, just continues to stare.

What do i do? Why is she staring at me for such a long time?

Comment: Not enough to constitute an answer: she's a cat.

Comment: what happens at the other end of your cat(the tail) when it stares at you,this is usefull information to make an answer as this can tell what mode the cat is in.

Comment: Well the tail is right to the side, not moving. I don't know if that helps.

Comment: the cat is probably waiting for you to do something and is letting you take the initiative.

Comment: Yes maybe that's true but I don't know what to do and sometimes i come pet her so she moves away.

Comment: She also does that sometimes after we play and we're done playing. I can't play for ever and she'll be tired after playing, I can't imagine she wants to play more. For your information the duration she spends playing for every season is an hour or half.

Answer (score 6):

I've no qualifications, so please don't take this as authoritative, but your cat's probably fine.

Cats tend to wag their tails when they're angry or tense. You pointed out in the comments that she's not doing that, so I imagine that she's just sitting peacefully on the floor and watching you. All this suggests to me is that you're more interesting to look at than the walls.

As for what to do? Pet her if you want, and if she's down for that.

Comment: I come to pet her and she moves away :(

Comment: @toothless199, just like humans, sometimes cats just aren't really in the mood for affection. If your cat is outright terrified of you and flees the room when you go near, there might be a problem. If you just go over there, say "hi", and she calmly wanders off, then I still don't see any cause for concern.

Comment: She's not a bet afraid of me infact I think she wants me to do something for her when she stares, I just don't know what

Comment: @toothless199, Cats just like watching stuff. If a human were to look at you the way your cat does, I'm sure that human would be expecting you to do something, but all the cats I've known are just perfectly happy to watch the humans around them as though they're slightly boring TV shows. As long as she's not terribly underweight, you're probably feeding her properly. You seem to play with her regularly, which is good. I really don't think this cat is in any way neglected, nor is she expecting anything more out of you.

Answer (score 0):

Direct eye contact for cats is a challenge. She is staring back at you as a response to your challenge and/or waiting for you to attack. If she's bored and wants to play, she may "attack" you first to get things started. My cats do this with each other all the time.

Slowly blinking or looking away signals that you don't intend to attack and that you trust the cat enough to not attack you, which builds trust. When my cats stare at me intently, I do one or the other, and they usually mirror the behavior and go back to whatever they were doing before.